# How to make toolbar with rounded corners and elevation inside appbarlayout? Like this picture

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

This is my code that I try to create toolbar with rounded corners shown in picture.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_actionbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

bg_actionbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<solid android:color="@color/white" />
<corners android:radius="16dp" />
</shape>
```

[image: This what I'm trying to create]
[image: This is what I'm getting]

Answer (score 10):

Set `app:elevation="0dp"` in `AppBarLayout`

And set `android:elevation="4dp"` to `Toolbar`

And also set 'android:layout_margin="4dp"' to Toolbar which will help you to show shadow.

So your layout will be like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
 android:id="@+id/appBar"
 app:elevation="0dp"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_margin="12dp"
 android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_actionbar" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, I also tried this, but it works in Api 21 and higher only, what about below api 21?

Comment: If you are considering those devices then you have to create a image bg with this kind of shadow in photo shop and set as background

Answer (score 0):

You May Try It:

> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_margin="20dp"
>         app:cardCornerRadius="14dp"
>         app:cardElevation="20dp">
>
>         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="ElementApp"
>                 android:textSize="24sp"
>                 android:textStyle="bold" />
>         </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
>     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
> </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
> ```

And the output will be like: [The output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHWpS.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use following xml file as a back ground and give specific radius as you requirement:

**shadowfile.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#18000000" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#05000000" />
            <corners android:radius="7dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#10000000" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#15000000" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#20000000" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Note : Here one item equals one layer, you can add or remove as per your requirements

Use in layout or toolbar :

```
android:background="@drawable/shadowfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toolbar without appbarlayout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_actionbar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you wrap it with cardview